# this.state.map is not a function in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, map-function

I can't map over the `responseData` fetched from server.Always getting error on map function.Following is my code.

**code**

**updated**

```
  onPressSubmit() {
        fetch("http://xxxxxxx", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            url: this.state.url
          })
        })
         .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((responseData) =>
        {
                this.setState({
                res:responseData,
                isLoading :false
                        }, () => { this.renderArticle()
                        });
            })
      }
renderArticle(){
      if(this.state.res && this.state.res.message && Object.values(this.state.res.message).length){
          return Object.values(this.state.res.message).map(ar =>
          <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => Actions.articleScreen({ unique: a.id })}
      >
        <CardSection>
          <View style={{ flexDirection: "row" }}>
            <Image
              source={{ uri: ar.image }}
              style={styles.thumbnail_style}
            />
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{ar.title}</Text>
          </View>
        </CardSection>
      </TouchableOpacity>
          );
      }else {
      return null;

      }
  }

    render(){
        return(
        <ScrollView>

            {article.map(a => (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => Actions.articleScreen({ unique: a.id })}
              >
                <CardSection>
                    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{a.title}</Text>
                </CardSection>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            ))}
         {this.renderArticle()}
            <Icon
              raised
              name="plus"
              type="font-awesome"
              color="#f49241"
              underlayColor="#f44941"
              onPress={() => this.popupDialog.show()}
            />
            <PopupDialog
              ref={popupDialog => {
                this.popupDialog = popupDialog;
              }}
              dialogStyle={{ backgroundColor: "#f2ddd5", height: 100 }}
              containerStyle={{ zIndex: 50, elevation: 100 }}
              overlayBackgroundColor="#000"
              dismissOnTouchOutside={true}
            >
            <View>
                <TextInput
                  style={{ height: 40 }}
                  placeholder="Enter the url you want to save!"
                  multiline
                  onChangeText={url => this.setState({ url })}
                  underlayColor="#fcc9b5"
                />

                <Button
      title='Ok' 
      onPress={() =>
     this.onPressSubmit()
        }/>
     </View>
            </PopupDialog>
         </ScrollView>
```

I'm not sure whether I'm doing correct please guide me..What is wrong with this code.Also the consoled output within `renderArticle` is following

[image: this is what I'm getting]

Comment: message is not array it's object. map is function of array prototype.

Comment: check `responseData` is Array or Object. You can console.log() it.if is it object so push it to array next set into `res`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this.state.res.message is an Object not an Array. So it is giving Error.

Solution to your issue can be :

```
renderArticle(){
  if(this.state.res && Object.values(this.state.res).length){
    return Object.values(this.state.res).map(ar => 
         //Your Previous Code
    );
  } else{
    return null
  }
}
```

You should call this method with in render function not in onPressSubmit.

```
render(){
 return(
   <View>{this.renderArticle()}</View>
 )
}
```

Comment: Yeah thank you , but new rows are being added ,content is not displaying. I mean `title`

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it.

Comment: This is what I'm getting. ^ new rows are being added without any content (I mean the responseData object)  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBCZH.png

Comment: May be it is a styling issue. You need to set the width and height for the  View and TouchableOpacity.

Comment: Yes I'm using the same style for my previous cards. Here 6new cards will be added. I think the object within `responseData` is taking individually.This is server response   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiJlk.png

Comment: Give me few minutes, i'll check.

Comment: Yes I got it. The mistake is Instead of mapping within message , I've changed it to res. i.e`return Object.values(this.state.res.message).map(ar => ` change it to `return Object.values(this.state.res..map(ar => `. Now its working cool..Thank you so much .I've stuck with this for days..Thank you for your great help..

Comment: My pleasure. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177480/discussion-between-anu-and-mohammed-ashfaq).

Comment: Actually 2rows are coming on a single click.1 with `title` and `image` while the other is empty.Like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGWmb.png

Answer (score 4):

You're using the [`map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which is a function that only exists on the Array prototype. Arrays can be mapped over because they're a list of items, but the item you're trying to map over (`this.state.message`) is an object.

This makes sense since you're requesting only one specific Medium article. You can render it to the DOM by accessing the object keys manually.

```
const { title } = this.state.res.message;

return (
  <View>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log("hii")}
      <CardSection>
        <Text>{title}</Text>
      </CardSection>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);
```